# Relation between Shanon entropy via relation of probabilities

Tags: entropy

We have two vectore of probabilities, $P=\left(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\right)$ and  $Q=\left(q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4\right)$. Assume that we know only the ralation between $p_i$ and $q_i$. To be more specific we know that $p_1 >q_1, p_4>q_4, p_2<q_2,p_3<q_3$',  additionally we can calculate the relations between each pair.
 I'm interested to know, the relation between entropies of this vectors.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What do "additionally we can calculate the relations between each pair" and "I'm interested to know, the relation between entropies of this vectors." mean, precisely?

Comment: Write $p_i = q_i x_i$. Then substitute that into $P$. Take the entropy of $P$ and $Q$ and compare.